# How to create an adjacency matrix from an input?

Tags: c, graph

Say I have the following raw data:

```
5 6
1 4 5
2 4 5
2 3 4
3 4 6
```

where first line represents: `[number of vertices] [number of edges]` and the subsequent lines represent: `[index of vertex1] [index of vertex2] [weight]`. I was thinking of doing `%3` and dividing data into 3 strings as vertices1, vertices2 and weights, but I cant find a proper way to arrange this data into an adjacency matrix. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried google?

Comment: Do you know at least what your adjacency matrix should look like?

Comment: of course I do, I am just confused a bit, also new to C so (yea ik)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probbaly you need this:

```
#include <stdio.h>    

#define MAXVERTICES 10    

int main(void)
{    
  int matrix[MAXVERTICES][MAXVERTICES];

  for (int i = 0; i < MAXVERTICES; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < MAXVERTICES; j++)
      matrix[i][j] = 0;

  int nbvertices, nbedges;    
  scanf("%d %d", &nbvertices, &nbedges);

  for (int i = 0; i < nbvertices; i++)
  {
    int v1, v2;
    int weight;
    scanf("%d %d %d", &v1, &v2, &weight);    
    matrix[v2][v1] = matrix[v1][v2] = weight;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

It's very basic, no error checking is done and the maximum number of vertices is 10 (MAXVERTICES).